# CREATE UNIQUE with distinct nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to put Java packages like **org.somepackage.parser** and **org.otherpackage.parser** into a neo4j database. I tried to solve the problem with the following cypher queries.

```
MATCH (root:package {isRoot: true})
CREATE UNIQUE (root)
<-[:subpackage]-(:package {name: 'org'})
<-[:subpackage]-(:package {name: 'somepackage'})
<-[:subpackage]-(:package {name: 'parser'})


MATCH (root:package {isRoot: true})
CREATE UNIQUE (root)
<-[:subpackage]-(:package {name: 'org'})
<-[:subpackage]-(:package {name: 'otherpackage'})
<-[:subpackage]-(:package {name: 'parser'})
```

Using the queries above the **parser** node just gets two relations to **somepackage** and **otherpackage**. I know that it's the expected behavior, but is there someway to get 2 different **parser** nodes? One linked to **somepackage** and the other linked to **otherpackage**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can add an attrib named `id` in your `parser` node and generate that id using java `randomUUID` or if you dont want to do that you can simply **rename** your parser nodes as

```
name: "org.otherpackage.parser" and  name: "org.somepackage.parser"
```

Comment: yes. that the way I solved the problem. But it feels like a hack ;)

Comment: i would say a smarter way to design